# Rails 6 model wont save in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I been working on a sort of gun display social media website thing but I ran into a problem where after I added the user_id to the gun model the save view will go to the create controller but wont save when the if save line (in the controller) is suppose to run. It worked in rails console but not by the controller.

schema

---

```rb
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2021_02_06_222048) do

  create_table "guns", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "year"
    t.string "model"
    t.string "condition"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.integer "user_id", null: false
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end
```

model

---

```rb
class Gun < ApplicationRecord belongs_to :users
```

view

---

```html
    <h1>Create your Gun here</h1>
    <form method = "post" action = <%=gun_index_url%>>
    <label for = "gun_model">Gun model</label>
    <input 
    type = "text"
    name = "gun[model]"
    id = "gun_model">

    <label for = "gun_condtion">Condtion</label>
    <input
    type = "text"
    name = "gun[condition]"
    id = "gun_condtion">

    <label for = year>Year manerfacterd</label>
    <input
    type = "number"
    value = "2000"
    name = "gun[year]"
    id = "gun_year">

    <input
    type = "hidden"
    value = "<%=current_user.id%>"
    name = "gun[user_id]"
    id = "user_id">

    <input
    type = "hidden"
    value = "<%=form_authenticity_token%>"
    name = "authenticity_token">

    <input type="submit" value="sumbit">
</form>
```

Controller model

---

```rb
class GunController < ApplicationController

    before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:new]

    def index
        @guns = Gun.all
        render :index
    end

    def new
        @gun = Gun.new
        render :new
    end

    def edit
        @gun = Gun.find(params[:id])
        render :edit
    end

    def create
        @gun = Gun.new(gun_params)
        if @gun.save
            redirect_to gun_url(@gun)
        else
            redirect_to new_gun_url
            raise ArgumentError.new
        end
    end

    def show 
        @gun = Gun.find(params[:id])
        render :show
    end
    
    def update 
        @gun = Gun.find(params[:id])
        if @gun.update(gun_params)
            redirect_to gun_url(@gun)
        else
            render :edit
            raise ArgumentError.new
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @gun = Gun.find(params[:id])
        @gun.destroy
        redirect_to gun_index_url
    end

    private

    def gun_params
        params.require(:gun).permit(:condition ,:year ,:model, :user_id)
    end
```

Comment: Hey I found out that if I remove the belongs_to :users part everything works fine how does the belongs_to

Comment: It should be `belongs_to :user`, was it a typo in the question?

Comment: no I thought the convention should be purlar thank you

Answer (score 1):

I found out that the
`belongs_to :users`
was not supost to be pular and should have been
`belongs_to :user`

Answer (score 0):

typically when a model wont save its a validation error. use the bang (!) methods to figure out what actually cases it..

so, instead of `save` use `save!` or instead of `update`, `update!`